# Job queue design on Windows Azure

Tags: c#, azure, queue

What design has someone successfully used to implement job processing on Windows Azure?

Requirements:

1. Ability to push a Job into a queue.
2. N workers can consume Jobs from the queue and process them.
3. Invoker of the job should be able to be alerted (push, not polling) of the job being completed.

Research thus far:

1. Create a "Job" Queue using *Azure Service Bus Queues* (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabric/archive/2011/05/17/an-introduction-to-service-bus-queues.aspx)
2. Web front-end pushes Jobs to the queue, workers block on Receive() indefinitely (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.aspx) until a Job is ready (to avoid "null" long polling, which costs money due to API call transaction costs)

With regards to being notified of Job completion:

1. There is no apparent ability to be alerted to when a Job has been completed.
   I thought I could leverage Service Bus Topics/Subscriptions (https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-topics/) and have a caller "subscribe to" a "Job Finished Notifications" topic, however:

   - You apparently can't subscribe more than once to the same topic, unless you create multiple "Subscription" entries (which does not scale)
   - Unless we did create a "Subscription" for each Job Id, and had the caller block on a Receive() API call (using I/O completion ports) on that subscription, we can't get real time notifications of when a Job has been processed.

Has anyone had any experience implementing this sort of Job system (real time, low latency, with completion notifications for the caller) before?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Actually, queue does not stand by push. The whole idea about queue is the receiver does not need to receive the message in real time, and wants to check the message periodically. If you need real time communication, you can create an HTTP/TCP listener on the receiver side, and let the sender make an HTTP/TCP request.

Thus, one approach is to create a web service on the web role, using internal endpoints. You send the service's address along with the message to worker role using queue. When the job is finished, the worker role invokes the service to notify the web role that job is done.

This approach is fine, but it does not provide much value. It cannot display something on the UI(unless you implement web socket), since a server cannot notify the browser. So if you want to display a notification in a browser client, I would like to suggest you to use a pull solution (unless you implement web socket). If you're using a rich client, you can host a web service on the client machine, and let the worker role notify the client by invoking the service.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.